# GIMP: Automatically blur/fade/mask edges of multiple layers

Tags: gimp, alpha-transparency, fading

I have many layers with irregular boundaries, and a background. I would like to "blend in" the images to the background by applying some sort of filter on their boundaries, gradually. Is there a way of doing this automatically?

What I tried is:

1. Merge all layers
2. Select the background of this combined layer
3. Invert selection
4. Apply feather to the selection
5. Fill in the selection with *white* colour *in the mask* layer

This method sort of works, but my problem is I have overlapping layers. This means the method above fades the boundaries of the layers *to the background* but not *to each other*.

I never tried scripting in GIMP, but I'm more than willing to try it, if anyone has a working solution.

Comment: This is more of a general usage question - and once you know what to do, you could then script it. As such, the question would be more suitable for superuser.com or maybe graphicdesign

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that can be scriptable.

Basically, scripting in GIMP can perform any action usually possible through the UI, and some that aren't.

So, once you identify the steps you need to perform for each desired layer -

like, selecting by color with maximum threshold and disalowing transparency - (that should give you a selection with the shape of the layers' visible contents).
Then, shrinking, inverting and feathering the selection 
and applying "gimp edit cut", or, programatically "gimp-edit-fill", with "TRASPARENT_FILL". 
For each of these actions, you can check the avaliable calls under `help->procedure_browser`.

Now, to create a GIMP Python script, what you have to do is:

create a Python 2 program that will import everything from the "gimpfu" module; place it as an exectuable in a GIMP`s plug-in folder (check the folders at`edit->preferences->folders`

In the script, you write your main function and any others - the main function may take as input parameters any GIMP object, like Image, Drawable, color, palette, r simply string and integer you want  -

And after that you place an appropriate call to the register `gimpfu.register` function - that will enable your script as a plug-in, with its own menu option in GIMP. Finish the script by placing a call to gimpfu.main().

Also, there are no "ready" ways for one to select a set of layers in a plug-in,rather than having just the currently active layer as input.  As a *very* convenient workaround for these cases, I abuse the "linked" layer marker (clicking on the layer's dialog, to the imediate right of the visibility icon will display a "chain" icon indicating a layer is linked)

All in all, the template for your plug-in is just:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8


import gimp
from gimpfu import *


def recurse_blend(img, root, amount):
    if hasattr(root, "layers"):
        # is image or layer group
        for layer in root.layers:
            recurse_blend(img, layer, amount)
        return
    layer = root
    if not layer.linked:
        return # Ignore layers not marked as "linked" in the UI.
    # Perform the actual actions:
    pdb.gimp_image_select_color(img, CHANNEL_OP_REPLACE, layer, (0,0,0))
    pdb.gimp_selection_shrink(img, amount)
    pdb.gimp_selection_invert(img)
    pdb.gimp_selection_feather(img, amount * 2)
    pdb.gimp_edit_clear(layer)


def blend_layers(img, drawable, amount):

    # Ignore drawable (active layer or channel on GIMP)
    # and loop recursively through all layers

    pdb.gimp_image_undo_group_start(img)
    pdb.gimp_context_push()
    try:
        # Change the selection-by-color options
        pdb.gimp_context_set_sample_threshold(1)
        pdb.gimp_context_set_sample_transparent(False)
        pdb.gimp_context_set_sample_criterion(SELECT_CRITERION_COMPOSITE)
        recurse_blend(img, img, amount)
    finally:
        # Try to restore image's undo state, even in the case
        # of a failure in the Python statements.
        pdb.gimp_context_pop()  # restores context
        pdb.gimp_selection_none(img)
        pdb.gimp_image_undo_group_end(img)


register(
    "image_blend_linked_layers_edges",  # internal procedure name
    "Blends selected layers edges",  # Name being displayed on the UI
    "Blend the edges of each layer to the background",
    "João S. O. Bueno",  # author
    "João S. O. Bueno",  # copyright holder
    "2018",              # copyright year(s)
    "Belnd layers edges", # Text for menu options
    "*",                  # available for all types of images
     [
        (PF_IMAGE, "image", "Input image", None),  # Takes active image as input
        (PF_DRAWABLE, "drawable", "Input drawable", None),  # takes active layer as input
        (PF_INT, "Amount", "amount to smooth at layers edges", 5),   # prompts user for integer value (default 5)
    ],
    [],  # no output values
    blend_layers, # main function, that works as entry points
    menu="<Image>/Filters/Layers",  # Plug-in domain (<Image>) followed by Menu position.
    )

main()
```